# Javascript function is not getting called onclick?

Tags: javascript, html

Can anyone see why this is not working?

I have a javascript function called addexercise()

```
<a href="#myModal_addexercise" onclick="addexercise('{{ $workout->name }}', '{{ $workout->workout_id }}'); return false;" role="button" data-toggle="modal" class="btn btn-success">
    Add Exercises
</a>
```

When I click the button Add Exercises it does work and the modal opens up but the onclick is not working.

Here is my JS I have at the end of the file:

```
<script>
function addexercise(name, workout_id) {
    alert(name);
    $('#modal-workout-name').html(name);
}
</script>
```

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

It does'nt appear that you are doing anything wrong, and next time try and put your code inside of an online editor, it will help you debug it before you ask the question. This time, someone did it for you.

Click here to see your unchanged code working:

http://codepen.io/nicholasabrams/pen/Pwwrwj

```
<a href="#myModal_addexercise" onclick="addexercise('{{ $workout->name }}', '{{ $workout->workout_id }}'); return false;" role="button" data-toggle="modal" class="btn btn-success">
    Add Exercises
</a>

<div id="modal-workout-name"></div>

function addexercise(name,workout_id) {
    alert(name);
    $('#modal-workout-name').html(name);
}
```

Comment: Hmmm okay so if my unchanged code does work in the above what could cause this not to work in what I am doing

Comment: Okay nevermind got it working.
Something in another javascript must have been messing with it.

Comment: @AlexWinter Press F12, look in the console, if you see $ is undefined then you need to include the jQuery library. If you do not see this then the problem is most likely that you have jQuery included in the wrong spot. Just a guess though until I can see the whole document